# CSS styles not working on already existing component/body tag

Tags: css, angular

I have a project in angular 7, I am loading a component dynamically using routes, in dynamically loaded component style-sheet I am adding some styles for body tag and already existing component tags and they're not reflecting in DOM.

```
body {
padding-bottom: 150px;
}
```

Styles are coming in the dynamically loaded component style-sheet, but I don't see them applying on DOM elements.

Comment: I found encapsulation with help of Dennis answer and for more details follow the link https://app.pluralsight.com/guides/css-encapsulation-in-angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default angular only applies the styles within a component, only to HTML elements within that components template (view encapsulation). To override this behaviour you can set an option in the components directive.

For more info see https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation

Comment: Thanks Dennis that helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you're defining styles within a component they will not apply outside of the component.

Check out my [StackBlitz template](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-template?embed=1&file=src/scss/styles.scss).

1. My global styles are defined in a scss/ folder to apply all global styles downwards into the DOM.
2. Component styles are then only used to override global styles or for component specific styles used no where else in my project.

This is how I set up my Angular styles. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks Ben, but Dennis answer is more relevant to me, I want to apply my styles outside the component whenever that component is loaded. For that I am using @Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
}) in specific component